# How to delete some empty directories from within the current directory?

Tags: directory, rm, delete

How to delete some empty directories from within the current directory?

Can I use `rmdir` for the job?

Comment: `rmdir` will *not* delete the current directory.  It won't delete anything unless you specify a directory to delete.

Comment: `rmdir` wont delete nothing. it's just a incomplete command. (Without options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is specify the empty directory as an argument:

```
rmdir /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `~` tilde before the path:

```
rm -rf ~/path/to/file
```

or

```
rmdir ~/path/to/file
```

you can remove a directory from anywhere, of course, within your user path and with the correct permissions.

Comment: This answer assumes that the directory lies under the current user's homedir. I know you state that being the case within the answer but OP didn't mention the specific location and this may confuse things further.